# 2 sample t test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, nonparametric

I was thinking that a simple 2 sample t test is not that simple when dealing with skewed data.

Considere 2 samples, each one with diferent skewness and kurtosis, both with a big sample sizes (say n > 40). Do the assumptions of 2 sample t test refer to the samples distributions themselves or two sample means distributions?

Particularly, does Welch's method corrects for heteroskedasticity in samples distribution or sample means distribution?
How differences in skewness and curtosis affect t test? What to do in such case?

Comment: Particularly with heavy skewness, I wonder if it’s really the means that you would be interested in comparing. You might be more interested in comparing population medians.